# Javascript: how to add the last number on each passing iteration?

Tags: javascript, loops, for-loop, google-apps-script, while-loop

Good Day,

How do you add the last row count number onto every passing, let's say the function repeatloop() code below passing 2000 for 1 pass, how do you add 2000 to each passing that happens so if the passing is 10 that would == to 20 000 at the end of 10 passing, please see my code below:

```
function rowcount()
{ 
 var token = getAccessToken();
 var module = "sHistory";
 var rows = 0;
 var go = true;
 var i = 1;
 var data;
 
  
  while (go) {
    //Utilities.sleep(10000)
   data = getRecordsByPage(i,200,token,module);
   
   if (Number(data.info.count) < 200) {
     go = false;
   };
   if ((i%10) == 0) {
      go = false; 
   }
   rows = Number(rows) + Number(data.info.count);
     i++;
  
     Logger.log("rowcount " + rows)
     }
     return rows
  }
 
 
function repeatloop()
{
 for(var i = 1; i <= 93; i++)
     {
       Utilities.sleep(10000)
       Logger.log(i);
       Logger.log(rowcount());
     }
     return rowcount();
}
```

So currently the output is doing this:

2:20:15 AM  Info    1.0
2:20:16 AM  Info    200.0
2:20:16 AM  Info    400.0
2:20:17 AM  Info    600.0
2:20:17 AM  Info    800.0
2:20:17 AM  Info    1000.0
2:20:18 AM  Info    1200.0
2:20:18 AM  Info    1400.0
2:20:18 AM  Info    1600.0
2:20:19 AM  Info    1800.0
2:20:19 AM  Info    2000.0
2:20:19 AM  Info    2000.0
2:20:19 AM  Info    0.0
2:20:29 AM  Info    2.0
2:20:30 AM  Info    200.0
2:20:31 AM  Info    400.0
2:20:31 AM  Info    600.0
2:20:31 AM  Info    800.0
2:20:32 AM  Info    1000.0
2:20:32 AM  Info    1200.0
2:20:32 AM  Info    1400.0
2:20:33 AM  Info    1600.0
2:20:33 AM  Info    1800.0
2:20:33 AM  Info    2000.0
2:20:33 AM  Info    2000.0
2:20:34 AM  Info    2000.0
2:20:34 AM  Info    200.0
2:20:34 AM  Info    400.0
2:20:35 AM  Info    600.0
2:20:35 AM  Info    800.0
2:20:35 AM  Info    1000.0
2:20:36 AM  Info    1200.0
2:20:36 AM  Info    1400.0
2:20:36 AM  Info    1600.0
2:20:37 AM  Info    1800.0
2:20:37 AM  Info    2000.0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Didn't get you well, but maybe you need something like:

```
let counter = 0;
function repeatloop() {
  for (var i = 1; i <= 10; i++) {
    Utilities.sleep(10000);
    Logger.log(i);

    counter += rowcount();
    Logger.log(counter);
  }
  return rowcount();
}
```

Comment: So what I mean is that every 1 pass output is 2000, what I want to happen is that after the next output is it adds another 2000 on the previous pass so on so forth, no matter how much the iterations happen it always adds 2000. for example pass 1 ends up with 2000 pass 2=4000 pass3=6000 etc

Comment: I changed the code a bit. Is it what you looking for?

Comment: No, it is not working, I am not sure why you put the repeatloop(2000); at the bottom, it just puts the number 2000 on the bottom line and not adding it to anything

Comment: It's passing an argument to the function `incrementBy`

Comment: I updated the code on my question to show you the output.it is not adding 2000 at the end of each iteration

Comment: Check again, please.

Is the `rowcount` function related to your question?

If not please remove it and all other parts too which are irrelevant, to make it easier

Comment: the row count is related to the question yes, as that row count is from another function

Comment: ok, it seems you need to increment by `rowcount()`. I updated the code

Comment: Thank you it is working, one last question, how do you make it so it only returns the increment of 2000 as its output.

Comment: I'm keeping the last value in `let counter = 0;` with this line `counter += rowcount();`

it means `counter = counter + rowcount();`